# javascript not pushing into array

Tags: javascript

I am looping round a json object and getting an item within the object which holds a comma delimited string,  I then split this string and check if its within the array and if not it should push it into the array. The problem is, it never pushes into the array

```
for (var item = 0; item < rules.length; item++) {
    //we now need to split the item by its delimiter which is a comma ','
    var treeSplit = rules[item].tree.split(',');

    if (treeSplit.length - 1 != childCount) {
        if (isInArray(treeSplit[childCount], aliasGroup)) {
            aliasGroup.push(treeSplit[childCount]);
        }
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```

This is my isInArray function it takes a value and the array

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

Comment: have you logged or debugged in the developers console?

Comment: Try console logging the treesplit variable to see if it has split the json object as you were expecting. It may be that the split isn't working as expected.

Comment: so I stuck a breakpoint in firebug on the isInArray line and it doesn't seem to want to go into the code inside that if statement

Comment: @Vistari It has split properly so I have a string hello,world it splits into an array held in treeSplit childCount is set to 0

Comment: Ah your if statement is incorrect when you're checking if it's in the array. You should negate it using `!` so that it will work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

> and if ***not*** it should push it into the array

You're missing the ***not***. You're pushing it into the array only if it is already in the array. Add a [logical not operator ( ! )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)) :

```
if ( ! isInArray(treeSplit[childCount], aliasGroup) ) {
    aliasGroup.push(treeSplit[childCount]);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I just noticed it when I was copying the code for further inspection. +1'ed